# loop multiple SQL queries and save output as single dataframe

Tags: python

I have a python script where I am trying to loop through multiple sql queries, take the outputs of those queries as simple count(*)'s, and concatenate them into one dataframe.

```
def function(query):

conn = ...

sql_query = open(query, 'r').read()

df_sql_output = pd.read_sql_query(sql_query,conn)
concatenated_data = []
if not df_sql_output.empty:
        concatenated_data.append(df_sql_output)
concatenated_data = pd.concat(concatenated_data, axis=1)
print(concatenated_data)
sqls = ['test1.sql','test2.sql','test3.sql']

for i in sqls:
    function(i)
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @roganjosh when I run this script it is not concatenating this into on df. Rather it is printing a different output for each query in the loop. So I am wondering how I can better loop through queries and concatenate the outputs into one dataframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just basic Python really. Your code isn't clear because you haven't indented it properly here, but in any case it can't work because `concatenated_data` is declared within the scope of `function` and is lost when the function exits. There's no way for its effects to persist. You need to learn how functions work. The Python tutorial is the place to look: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions. In the meantime here is roughly how to fix your code worrying about wrapping anything in a function:

```
conn = ...

query_paths = ['test1.sql', 'test2.sql', 'test3.sql']

query_results = []

for query_path in query_paths:

    with open(query_path) as file:
        query = file.read()

    query_results.append(pd.read_sql_query(query, conn))

result = pd.concat(query_results)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This was super helpful. I am on week two of learning Python so I will check out that tutorial you recommended.

Answer (score 0):

This is the rough idea how can we do it. If you update your code. I can update my answer.

```
import pandas as pd


sqls = ['test1.sql','test2.sql','test3.sql']

def func(query):
    conn = ...
    df = pd.DataFrame()
    if len(df) == 0:
        df = pd.read_sql(query_string,conn)
    else:
        df_temp = df.copy()
        temp = pd.read_sql(query_string,conn) 
        df = pd.concat([df, df_temp], ignore_index=True)
    return df

for query in sqls:
    func(query)
```